# Put language switcher in the header

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate-x, language-switching

I am trying to change the language switching tool in my WordPress website. Currently the option to choose the language is shown in the main menu (this is the website http://www.moncheri.al/en/, the plugin used for this is qTranslate-X) but I want to display it in header, top right corner like this http://www.novacontract.al/en

Answer (score 0):

Use `qtranxf_generateLanguageSelectCode('text');` function in your header.php.

In your website use the code right after the social icons.

Comment: ok now it works, but the two languages display overlayed, how can I separate them?

Comment: You may have to do some CSS based adjustments

Comment: I tried every CSS possible but I couldn't fix the text display. However, I used the qtranxf_generateLanguageSelectCode('image') and I used the language widget inside a sidebar selecting only image, so now it works using the flags. Thanks anyways :)